# How to use paths in SCSS with Angular for Electron?

Tags: node.js, angular, sass, electron

I use Angular 10 and Electron 10 in combination with a SCSS stylesheet. One of my assets is available at  `.../project/src/assets/img/foo.png`. During development I use the style below:

```
.background {
   background-image: url("/assets/img/foo.png");
}
```

Running this as a production build fails and the app can't find this asset. Instead I have to remove the `/` which then works. So it needs to look like this:

```
.background {
   background-image: url("assets/img/foo.png");
}
```

What is the proper path syntax for development and production builds?
P.S. Removing `/` in the "development" build raises this exception:

```
Can't resolve './assets/img/foo.png' in '/Users/.../src/app/page'

  17 | 
  18 | .background {
> 19 |   background-image: url("assets/img/foo.png");
```